# Modeling justification for no standard errors of random effect estimates in R mixed model packages?

Tags: r, standard-error

None of the `nlme`, `multilevel`, or `lme4` mixed effect programs seem to offer estimates of the variability of the *random effects*' variance/covariance estimates (in contrast with MLWin, Stata, etc.).

I find this lack of standard errors surprising (although, I might simply be uninformed about the R packages' functionality), as this implies not hypothesis testing, and no confidence intervals for these estimates.

**Is it considered acceptable to not employ standard tools of statistical inference for random effects?**

Comment: In nlme, `intervals()` gives confidence intervals for the random effects. For example, `fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age, data = Orthodont); intervals(fm1)`

Comment: @mark999 Huh! That's interesting... I see now that the document mentions "intervals" up top, but doesn't actually detail that function the way it does the others. Ok. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what document you're referring to. If you haven't already, try looking at "Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-Plus" by Pinheiro and Bates, and "Linear Mixed Models for Longitudinal Data" by Verbeke and Molenberghs. The latter has a chapter called "Inference for the Random Effects".

Comment: @mark999 I've been using the different packages to estimate some models, and comparing to Stata's mixed modeling capacity. I have been getting by with the package documentation and a few tutorials around the web. Just surprised that these quantities are not part of the standard output (e.g. `fm1`, or `summary(fm1)`). Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I must admit that I find mixed-effects models quite difficult to understand and work with.

Comment: @mark999 I have found this article to be an classic in motivating multilevel thinking (at least *cross-sectionally*... of course longitudinal designs also invoke mixed-effects models in their own ways, and single-level heterogeneous variation may be of interest, too, but this is a decent orientation): Duncan, C., Jones, K., and Moon, G. (1998). Context, composition and heterogeneity: Using multilevel models in health research. *Social Science & Medicine*, 46(1):97–117.